# MVC PagedList Query String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I'm using pagedList.mvc to do some pagination. The query filtering seems to work fine, however when paginating to the second page, the query string doesn't seem to work. Any advice would be great.

The examples [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) didn't really help much because I'm performing multiple filters and I'm using a model in the form, not ViewBag.

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult People(int? page, StaffProfilesVM model)
    {
        var profiles = this.Context.StaffProfileInternal.GetAll();

        if (model == null)
        {
            var VM = new StaffProfilesVM();
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> interests = BindInterests(model.researchInterests);
            List<ProfileAffiliation> affiliations = BindAffiliations(model.affiliations);

            //apply filters
            profiles = ApplyFilters(model, interests, affiliations, profiles);
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        int pageSize = 6;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        model.StaffProfiles = profiles.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

        return View(model);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<StaffProfileInternal>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)

<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" align="center">
    <div aria-label="Page navigation">

        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of   @Model.PageCount 
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("People",
            new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
    </div>
</div>
```

The filter works correctly and returns the first page fine. When paginating to the second/other pages, the query string is applied to currentFilter, but the extra characters in the query string prevent the query from being executed. How can I handle this?

**WORKS**
Home/People?PersonId=&Classification=Unknown&affiliations=1

**DOES NOT WORK**
Home/People?page=2&currentFilter=PersonId%3D%26Classification%3DUnknown%26affiliations%3D1

Thank you.

Comment: You don't assign the QueryString to a ViewBag property. You need to assign each value of the model, and then `new { page, PersonId = Model.PersonId, Classification = Model.Classification ....`

Comment: This seems to work for properties, but not lists. I have two multiselect lists that I'm using as filters, how would I handle this?

Comment: You cannot send collections or complex objects as query strings (or route values). Internally the method uses `.ToString()` for each property (so you would get `someProperty=System.Collections.Generic....` You need to build the query string for each value in the collection - `someProperty=2&someProperty=5&someProperty=6.....`

Comment: I decided using PagedList wasn't going to give me the flexibility I needed. I decided to use Kendo Listview to display the results, cache them, and run build a search processor that can handle filtering on child objects. Thanks for your comments.